# List Null Post Ajax Asp.NET MVC 5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou tentando realizar um post de um LIST via ajax, só que no controller sempre está chegando null.

Código da requisição:

```
var Componentes = [{ Nome: "Teste1" }, {Nome: "Teste2"}];
$.ajax({
         type: "post",  
         url: '@Url.Action("Cadastrar","DocumentoDinamico")',
         data: JSON.stringify(Componentes),  
         datatype: "json",  
         cache: false,  
         success: function (data) {
              console.log('Sucesso.');
         },  
         error: function(data) {  
             console.log('Erro. ' + data);
         } 
 });
```

Código do model:

```
public class Componente
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Código do controller:

```
public ActionResult Cadastrar(List<Componente> Componentes)
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver adicionado este código na requisição:

```
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```